# How can I add or enable a Position Indicator in SingleChildScrollView

Tags: dart, flutter

I need a scroll position indicator for my multi line `TextField` which is wrapped in a `SingleChildScrollView`.

[image]

There is more text in the text field than is visible and I it's not obvious that there is some text hidden and where it's hidden (top or bottom)

This is Whatsup. The TextField shows a scrollbar. I would like to do the same thing.
[image]

Comment: Example ? Not clear

Comment: The Textfield above has many lines of content but there only a few visible. In order for the user to understand that there is much more content I would like to show a Scrollbar on the right hand site of the TextField.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Just wrap your `TextField` widget in a `ScrollBar` widget.

Example:

```
new Container(
  height: 100.0,
  child: new Scrollbar(
    child: new TextField(
      maxLines: null,
    )
  ),
)
```

For more info on `ScrollBar` widget check out the docs [here](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/Scrollbar-class.html)

Hope that helped!

Comment: this did not work for me without setting a common `ScrollController` on the `Scrollbar` and the child in my case a `ListView` from a `Builder`.

Answer (score 14):

Thanks for the answer above:The `SingleChildScrollView` gave me the desired behavior I was looking for combined with the LayoutBuilder and and the constraints: new BoxConstraints:

```
    Widget _renderTextField() => new LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (context, constraints) => new Column(children: <Widget>[
            new Container(
                    child: new Container(
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                      right: 5.0,
                    ),
                    child: new Container(
                        constraints: new BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 200.0,
                        maxWidth: constraints.maxWidth),
                        child: new Scrollbar(child: new SingleChildScrollView(
                                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                                reverse: true,
                                child: new TextField(...
```

Answer (score 10):

for `SingleChildScrollView` just wrap it in `RawScrollbar`

```
body: RawScrollbar(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
                           child: ...
                                    ),
                  ),
```

Answer (score 2):

I create a dialog with a form and a child container with a width and height of 450 and 500.  I use a layoutbuilder to create a textboxform whose max height is 200 with a scrollbar and singlechildscrollview.  The row is expanded to take the all the width of the widget.  I have two material buttons with action included.

```
 String _myvalue;
 final _myTextController = TextEditingController();
 final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
 final _scrollController = ScrollController();

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
       return Dialog(
          child: Form(
             key: _formKey,
             autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.disabled,
             child: Container(
                 width: 450,
                 height: 500,
                child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child: Text(
                      "Some Text",
                      style: Head2Style,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Divider(height: 50),
                  LayoutBuilder(
                      builder: (context, constraints) => Container(
                          constraints: new BoxConstraints(
                              maxHeight: 200.0,
                              maxWidth: constraints.maxWidth),
                          child: Scrollbar(
                              isAlwaysShown: true,
                              controller: _scrollController,
                              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                                  controller: _scrollController,
                                  child: SizedBox(
                                      width: 400,
                                      child: TextFormField(
                                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                                              icon: Icon(Icons.note),
                                              hintText: "My Text"),
                                          autocorrect: true,
                                          controller: _myTextController,
                                          keyboardType:
                                              TextInputType.multiline,
                                          maxLines: null,
                                          maxLength: 1000,
                                          onChanged: (String value) {
                                            setState(() {
                                              _myvalue = value;
                                            });
                                          })))))),
                  Expanded(
                      child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                    children: [
                      ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                            _do_something(context);
                          }
                        },
                        child: Text("Do something"),
                      ),
                      ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          Navigator.of(context).pop();
                        },
                        child: Text("Cancel"),
                      )
                    ],
                  )),
      ])//column
      )//container
   )//form
   )//dialog;
}
```