# how to make scrollable multiline input text in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

sorry I am new in Flutter. I have tried to find it in Stackoverflow but I can't find it.

I need to make something like this

[image]

something like a box that **has fix height and width** with a **multiline input and also scrollable**. in native iOS, I can easily use TextView, but I don't know the equivalent for Flutter.

I have tried to make it by using Textfield like this

```
   TextFormField(
      autofocus: true,
      autocorrect: false,
      keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
      maxLines: null,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        filled: true,
        fillColor: Color(0xFFF2F2F2),
        border: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
          borderSide: BorderSide(width: 1),
        ),
      ),
    ),
```

but it doesn't have scrolling ability and I can't set the fix height. please help ...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54972928/how-to-expand-a-textfield-in-flutter-looks-like-a-text-area

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you just need to set minLines and maxLines shown below, For the box, maxLines do the works for you to set height, And for width, you can wrap TextFormField into a container and gave it manually width.

```
TextFormField(
  autofocus: true,
  autocorrect: false,
  keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
  minLines: 1,
  maxLines: 8,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    filled: true,
    fillColor: Color(0xFFF2F2F2),
    border: OutlineInputBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
      borderSide: BorderSide(width: 1),
    ),
  ),
),
```

Comment: this is correct, and to add scrollbar inside a textfield, just add the scrollbar like the answer in here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48321648/9101876

Answer (score 1):

If you have your Textfield inside of a Column alongside other static elements, you can constrain the Textfield in height by getting the device screen height (MediaQuery) and multiplying by the needed factor ( between 0 and 1) and set the scrollPhysics parameter of your TextField/TextFormField to "AlwaysScrollablePhysics()"

```
Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8),
              child: Text(FlutterI18n.translate(ctx, 'tour.clipboardNote.content'), style: TextStyle(fontSize: TextSize.medium),),
            ),
            ConstrainedBox(
              constraints: BoxConstraints(maxHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.5),
              child: TextFormField(
                controller: noteController,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                minLines: null,
                maxLines: null,
                scrollPhysics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        )
```

[image: Much text]

[image: Less text]